# Hidden DataGridView column doesn't display data when made visible again

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is bound to and XML file, the XML file may contain a certain field, but may not. If the field is there I want to show the relevant DataGridView column, if not I want to hide it.

I've achieved this by setting the columns visible property. The issue I have is, if I load an XML file without the field (so the column is made not visible), then load an XML file with the field, the column is visible again but the data doesn't appear for this column.

I'm using the below code to load the XML files.

```
xmlDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
xmlDataSet.ReadXml(_tempAccessXMLFile);

xmlDataGridView.DataSource = xmlDataSet;
xmlDataGridView.DataMember = "key";

xmlDataGridView.Refresh();
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Thanks,
(Also, apologies if this isn't a well formatted or unclear, I'm not very good at wording things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution, of sorts. I don't think the issue was anything to do with hiding the columns, but was simply because there was no data for the columns when the data was first bound. I've just added dummy records for the hidden fields to the file which didn't have them. This works for me, the data appears as I need.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the column name loads in grid but data is not displayed then try using `BindingSource`. I have tested it using `books.xml` sample XML File and works fine

```
xmlDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(_tempAccessXMLFile, new XmlReaderSettings());

dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource =  dataSet.Tables["book"];

xmlDataGridView.DataSource =bs;
xmlDataGridView.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but this seems to have the same issue. Column headers are loaded, but the data for those columns isn't.